# Limit for Related Look-up Lists

Tags: custom-object, lookup, contact, related-list

Suppose let's say I have 100 custom objects, and they all have a look up relation with Contacts. Are so many related lists supported? If so, can anyone give the max number of look-up lists supported in Sales force? 
[image: Salesforce related list]

Comment: There is a limit of 25 lookup fields on 1 object, however not sure how many references it can have. Very good question!

Answer (score 4):

You can have as many custom objects as you want, you just can't reference them in your workflow, formula fields and validation rules during the same execution context by spanning more than 10 objects. As an aside, there's a similar limit of 10 when it comes to namespaces.

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000171213&language=en_US) there is a maximum number of 10 object references on ObjectName. This number can be increased to 15 by filing a case with Salesforce. Determining Spanning relationship numbers can be complex and isn't as straightforward as it might seem on the surface.

[Understanding Spanning Relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000006372) goes into the subject in depth, including different ways of trying to work around this limit and how relationships of objects with another object can affect the spanning calculation. No more than 10 different objects can be referenced in a combination of formulas, validation rules and workflow in the same execution context.

As an example: You have a validation rule that references 3 unique objects, a field update that references 4 other objects and a formula field that references 3 other objects. That would put you over the limit 10 (original object + 10 = 11).

As a workaround, triggers and junction objects can be used to reduce the references. This is explained in the documentation I've cited.

Comment: I don't see what your answer actually is. Is there no set maximum to the number of related lists which can be added?

Comment: Not that I could find. The real issue is that regardless of how many you add, you can only reference 10 of them at one time.

Comment: @AdrianLarson What I did find was this: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000206401 which is basically the effect of too many related lists on visualforce page performance and how to improve it. Also found [Considerations for Relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there can be as many as 40 Look-up relationships between two objects. However, am not sure about the maximum an object can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

a child object can have at max 25 lookup master

Answer (score -2):

I believe is 12 and can be increased to 15 by contacting SF support - according to the following issues/ideas:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gKsbAAE

https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-25906

Comment: I have references to 14 Custom Objects and some Standard Objects in Contacts. Sales force hasn't given me any error!

Comment: Try create 2 more to see if 15 is set as a standard nowadays...

Comment: I now have about 18 test objects, a field from each of them have a look-up relation to Contacts. 2 Test objects have 25 fields which all have a look-up relation to Contacts as well (max limit for an object). I think the 15 limit is for Cases? and not for the Contacts

Comment: Per the discussion at the linked Idea, the limit is not on lookup fields, but on formula field references to a related object. You can have up to 25 relationship fields (2 of which can be M/D) on a single object, but you can't reference more than 10 objects in formula fields. 

This also refers to Case being the child of all these references, not the Parent, so I don't think this limit goes to the asked question. I cannot find any published limit on a maximum number of child relationships.